# Can't make directory because the directory exists?

Tags: bash, git-bash

I am trying to extract a list of mp3 files into 2 parts: 1 for artist and 1 for song name. So far, I have this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.mp3; do
        artist="${f%  -*}"
        song="${f#*-\ }"
        mkdir "$artist"
        mv "$f" "$song"
        mv "$song" "$artist";
done
```

I am testing on a file I created called "hi - 1.mp3" (`hi/ -/ 1.mp3`) but get the error 
`mkdir: cannot create directory ‘hi - 1.mp3’: File exists` which prevents changing the song name and moving it into the directory.
I thought this was a directory issue so I tried to manually check if the directory exists:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.mp3; do
        artist="${f%  -*}"
        song="${f#*-\ }"
        if [ -d "$artist" ]; then
                exit 0
                mkdir $"$artist"
fi
        mv "$f" "$song"
        mv "$song" "$artist";
done
```

But because the error is that a directory exists, it doesn't do anything and just results in `exit 0` (although I don't have the mkdir error anymore.)
I also have tried `ls -a` on all my directories but I can't find another a directory with the name hi - 1.mp3

Comment: what's the value of `"$artist"`?; have you tried `mkdir -p "$artist"`?

Comment: didn't you want the `mkdir` to be inside of an `else` block? With an `exit` just before it, it will never be executed. Add debugging statements so you know that your `"${f#*-\}"` stuff is working as you expect, ie. print "artist=$artist". Good luck.\

Comment: I just noticed that $artist that mkdir is working with is ```mkdir -p hi - 1.mp3``` However, I thought ```"${f%*-\}"``` strips the file name of everything after the dash?

Comment: make that `echo "artist=${artist}"` . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have u tried this....it is perfectly working fine...fr my case.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
 for f in *.mp3
 do
 artist=`echo ${f%-*}`
 song=`echo ${f#*-}`
 mkdir -p $artist
 mv "$f" "$song"
 mv $song ./$artist
 done
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash should continue even after giving the error unless you have used set -e, you could add a `set +e` in your script to reverse this behavior and continue to run after having a command fail. From `help set`:

> -e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.

Also, you could use mkdir -p, which will supress the error. From `man mkdir`:

> ```
>    -p, --parents
>           no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
> ```